# Excel: Can I find the sum of individual rows using an overarching formula?

Tags: excel, sum

I am not super well versed in Excel, but what I'm trying to do is find the sum of individual rows without having to type a different form in for each one.

I have this as my data table, and I need a sum of `columns C through P` in the `Q row`:

[image]

I know I can use the formula `=SUM(C2:P2)` but I would need to retype that and change the numbers for each row, and I have over 100,000 rows so that's not exactly feasible. If someone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Uh, basically excel can automatically fill in the formula you need. Type `=SUM(C2:P2)` in Q2, select Q2, and click twice at the lower right corner of Q2. If this doesn't work, another way is by moving you cursor at the lower right corner and it will turn into a little cross. Hold your mouse a scroll down, then the formulas are completed. The third way is to find the button called "auto-fill". However my excel is not eng. version, therefore I'm sorry that I can't give you the exact name and steps of it.

Comment: Maybe use `=SUM($C2:$P2)` and drag down to the end.  It will automatically change the row reference for you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when copying or filling formulas, excel will automatically change the reference according to where you copied/filled the formulas.

To fill down a formula, after entering it into Q2, you can left-click on the square on the bottom right hand corner of cell Q2 and drag it down.

If every cell in column P has a value, then you can just double click on the square on the bottom right corner of cell Q2. Excel will then automatically copy it down as far as there are values in the adjacent P column.